# Sum of all the digits till it becomes single digit in java with o(1) complexity?

Tags: java, logic, complexity-theory

I found the answer for this from Henry

```
int sum = n % 9;
if (sum == 0) sum = 9;
```

here

[java program that sums up the digits of a number until it is a single number Eg: 2748303 = 2+7+4+8+3+0+3 = 27 = 2+7 = 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940981/java-program-that-sums-up-the-digits-of-a-number-until-it-is-a-single-number-eg)

Can any one please explain how adding digits and remainder are related?

My logic also would have been as below which is also mentioned in above link

```
int sum = 0;
    while (n > 9 ) {
                 sum=0;
        while (n > 0) {
            int rem;
            rem = n % 10;
            sum = sum + rem;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        n = sum;
    }
```

But 2 line answer is awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java integers have a limited range, therefore taking a reminder has *O(1)* asymptotic complexity.

Now to your main question:

> Can any one please explain how adding digits and remainder are
>   related?

First note that any number `n` has the same reminder when divided by 9 as the sum of its digits. In case this does not seem immediately obvious here is a sketch of a proof.

**Proof**

Let `nk,...,n2,n1,n0` be the `k+1` digits of the number `n`.

Let `10^p` denote the `p`-th power of 10.

Then

```
n = 10^k * nk + ... + 100 * n2 + 10 * n1 + n0 =
  = (10^k - 1) * nk + ... + (100-1) * n2 + (10-1) * n1 +
    + nk + ... + n2 + n1 + n0
```

Now note that the last line is the sum of digits of the number `n`

```
  S0 = nk + ... + n2 + n1 + n0
```

Let

```
 S1 = (10^k - 1) * nk + ... + (100-1) * n2 + (10-1) * n1
```

is divisible by 9 since `10^p - 1 = 9...9` is divisible by 9 for all `p > 0`.

Since `n = S1 + S0` and S1 is divisible by 9, it follows that S0 % 9 = n % 9.

**That is what we wanted to prove**

Now let `S(n)` denote the function that returns the sum of digits of the number `n`, then as we have just observed

```
  n % 9 = S(n) % 9 = S(S(n)) % 9 = ...
```

We can continue  process until we reach a single digit number.

This is how the reminder and the sum of digits are related.

Comment: As you mention, this only proves that n%9 = S*(n)%9. It doesn't prove that n%9 and S(n) are the same, because they are actually not (there is the 9 != 0 case). S(n) is however equal to (n-1)%9+1.

Comment: @andresp this is a good point, and it is already handled in the original post: `int sum = n % 9; if (sum == 0) sum = 9;`